# How to divide a webpage in different sections?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page which has length of 2000px, but I want to divide it into 4 different sections (ie. 500px each) so I can add different content there with different design. But I have no idea how to do it. I would like to give hyperlinks of them also.

Comment: *div*ide or *div*ision

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need some fundamentals.

The structure of your page is HTML, while stylistic elements are dictated in CSS. So you'll want four logical divisions (a.k.a. `<div></div>`) inside of a containing `<div></div>`, like this:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

A `div` is something called a block level element, which will automatically expand to the full width (ie: 100%) of its container. You want the inner `div` elements to take of equal width, and since there's four of them you do some math.

100%/4 = the width you want each `div` to be.

```
<div>
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>    
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>
    <div style="width:25%;"></div>
</div>
```

You'll notice this doesn't work as expected since the `div` elements will be the width you want but only stack on top of each other. To get them next to each other, you can use `display:inline-block;` which changes the block level to something between block and inline.

```
<div>
    <div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div>    
    <div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

This will be almost what you want, except you will notice some gaps between the `div` elements, which is actually white space being preserved in the HTML code (the line breaks between the `<div></div>`). There are several ways of getting rid of this. In my opinion, the easiest is to put a blank comment between the elements, like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div><!--
    --><div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div><!--    
    --><div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div><!--
    --><div style="width:25%; display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

This is using CSS styles inside the HTML elements, but you should really put [CSS in a stylesheet and reference it in the page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Comment: Thanx Buddy....but i was wondering if it would work in leangth also (i.e. Length:25%) coz i want to divide it lenghwise...

Comment: The `width` attribute handles width along the x axis, the `height` attribute handles height along the y axis. There is no length attribute in css.

Answer (score 0):

a terrible answer is frames; a moderately bad answer is css  divs

```
<div class="bottom">
  <div id="area1" style="float: left; width: 25%;"></div>
  <div id="area2" style="float: left; width: 25%;"></div>
  <div id="area3" style="float: left; width: 25%;"></div>
  <div id="area4" style="float: left; width: 25%;"></div>
</div>
```

now when you say hyperlinks.. do you mean as in you click the mini part of the page and it expands to that part of it? because you will probably have to do some jquery hack for it

```
$("#area1").click(function(){
$("#area1").css("width", "100%");
$("area2").css("width", "0%");
$("area3").css("width", "0%");
$("area4").css("width", "0%");
});
```

(the above should resize the clicked div for the quarter you clicked on to 100 while shrinking the others. you would then style the individual div in the css for it by id or class etc.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is syntax for jquery.I have not done that yet...Any Help would we appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

easy way for you to use bootstrap that provides already make columns and with responsive functionality.IF you don't want to use next option is we can use css or frames.like as above answer